# How to solve error on HttpURLConnection in android with URL having special characters?

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-httptransport

I am trying to call a get API call using HttpURLConnection in android. I am passing some values as headers on the URL. This API returns not found response if that value contains special characters like & and #. All other special characters working fine. See below the method that I have used to call service.

```
URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        con.setRequestProperty("UserId", "787878");
        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setDoOutput(false);
        con.connect();

        InputStream inputStream;
        status = con.getResponseCode();
        statusmsg = con.getResponseMessage();
```

Comment: try `new URL(strings[0])` to `new URL(URLEncoder.encode(strings[0], "utf-8"))`

Comment: @snachmsm tried but crashed with 'System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:' error

Comment: Indeed that happens if you url encode the whole url so http:// too. You should only url encode the values in the querystring of the url. So starting behind the questionmark.

Comment: @blackapps Tried but getting Internal Server Error

Comment: Please show your url.